# Getting some issues while dockerizing an angular application by fetching the code from github

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, containers

[image: This is the image of the steps that needs to be done using a dockerfile and a kubernetes file.]

[image: This is the Dockerfile that I have written to perform the tasks but it's not running properly and I am not able to figure out the error.]

I will be very thankful if anybody can help me out with this dockerfile and kubernetes conf file to perform the following tasks.
I wanted to create a Dockerfile which can fetch the source code of an angular app from github and build it and also push it to the docker hub.
I have tried with the Dockerfile below but there are issues with the file. If anyone can guide me to the mistakes I have done or can provide a suitable Docker file then it will be great.
Also If possible I also want to ask for the kubernetes conf file which can pull the image from the dockerhub and run it as a service.
Thank You.

Comment: You seem to have included an image file in the question; what is it, and how does it relate to your task?  Do you have a Dockerfile, Kubernetes YAML, or any other source code you could include in the question (as text, not an image)?  What problem are you running into?  The one thing I can say is that it's usually not a best practice to pull the source code from the Dockerfile itself but usually better to check the Dockerfile into the repository with the application, but that's not an answer on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have Docker and Kubernetes solutions setup and ready.

First, as mentioned by the others, the best option is just to use [Dockerfile from the repo](https://github.com/wkrzywiec/aston-villa-app/blob/master/Dockerfile) instead of writing your own:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/aston-villa-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Please [clone the repo](https://github.com/wkrzywiec/aston-villa-app):

```
git clone https://github.com/wkrzywiec/aston-villa-app.git
cd aston-villa-app
```

Create your Docker repository - steps are [presented here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/) - in this example I will create a public repository named `testing-aston-villa-app`.

Login to the [Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) on your host:

```sh
docker login
...
Login Succeeded
```

[Build and push Docker image to your repo - commands are like this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/#step-4-build-and-push-a-container-image-to-docker-hub-from-your-computer):

```sh
docker build -t <your_username>/my-private-repo .
docker push <your_username>/my-private-repo
```

In our example (make sure that you are in the directory where repo is cloned):

```sh
docker build -t {your-username}/testing-aston-villa-app .
docker push {your-username}/testing-aston-villa-app
```

Ok, image is now on your Docker repository. Time to use it in Kubernetes. Please do below instructions on the host where you [have `kubectl` installed and configured to interact with your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/).

Following yaml file has definitions for [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)  and for [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). In `image` field please use `<your_username>/my-private-repo` name:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aston-villa-app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aston-villa-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aston-villa-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aston-villa-app
        image: {your-username}/testing-aston-villa-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aston-villa-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: aston-villa-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Please save this yaml and run `kubectl apply -f {file.yaml}`.

After applied, check if pods are up and service exits:

```
kubectl get pods,svc
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
pod/aston-villa-app-deployment-5f5478b66d-592nd       1/1     Running     0               13m
pod/aston-villa-app-deployment-5f5478b66d-vvhq2       1/1     Running     0               13m

NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/aston-villa-app-service   ClusterIP   10.101.176.184   <none>        80/TCP      13m
```

Now, let's check if service is working by making request to it from another pod:

```sh
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # wget 10.101.176.184
Connecting to 10.101.176.184 (10.101.176.184:80)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |*****************************************************************************|   596  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
/ # cat index.html 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AstonVillaApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/as_logo.svg">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Note that I used IP address `10.101.176.184` because it's the IP address of the `service/aston-villa-app-service`. In your case, it will be probably different.

Comment: After building the image I am unable to run that image, While using the docker run command it is just hanging on that spot without returning the control over to me and without showing any logs of executing..??

Comment: Could you please provide exact `docker run` command that you are running?

Comment: It's working now , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a working Dockerfile in the repo that you can use. You can just clone the repo and build it.

If you can't do that and want to clone the repo from inside the Dockerfile, you can modify it like this

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS build
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN git clone https://github.com/wkrzywiec/aston-villa-app.git
WORKDIR /aston-villa-app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build /aston-villa-app/dist/aston-villa-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Build and run with

```
docker build -t aston .
docker run -d -p 5000:80 aston
```

Then go to http://localhost:5000/ in a browser.

As for getting it to run on AWS/Kubernetes, I suggest making a new question for that. You should only have one question in a Stackoverflow post.